# iOS Core Data prevent duplicate object insertion

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data

I am a newbie iOS programmer and I want to store data entered in my app's user interface to Core Data. For sake of simplicity take a an example of Student, every student has a "rollNo" which is unique and not null. I just want to confirm that once a student with a particular roll number, say 101, is saved, then Core Data will not store the new student with the same roll number.

How do I accomplish this?

Also I know that Core Data is not a database so there is no concept of any primary key so what is the alternative to this?

I also searched over the net and I got some answers from Stackoverflow, but they all say to get all the data from Core Data using a fetch request and compare the new object with all of the objects that are obtained from the fetched request but it is not what I am looking for because it degrades the performance when there are a lot of objects already in Core Data.

Comment: You must have read the wrong answers or didn't understand them correctly, you need to create a fetch request with a predicate conditions ensuring the object being unique. Then, if you get one, you use it, otherwise you create a new instance and set the unique values immediately.